# how can i sum two numbers and show the result in alert windows {Html & Javascript}

Tags: javascript, html

i have made a code but its shows the result in textfiled and i want it to show in
alert window {pop up window}
this is my code :

```
 <html>
  <head>
        <title>Input tutorial</title>
        <script language="javascript">
                function addNumbers()
                {
                        var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                        var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                        var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                        ansD.value = val1 + val2;
                }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        value1 = <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="1"/>
        value2 = <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2" value="2"/>
        <input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click here" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()"/>
        Answer = <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" value=""/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: alert(ansD.value)

Comment: can you edit my code and send it back to me ......bec am new in coding.......so plz help me

Comment: You want to alert the result ?

Comment: @IPreview: `"can you edit my code and send it back to me"` - You don't have a text editor on your computer?  That would be a more immediate problem for you to solve before doing *any* programming.  Stack Overflow is a very poor replacement for your own computer.

Comment: solved
Replace

var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
ansD.value = val1 + val2;
With

alert(val1+val2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
ansD.value = val1 + val2;
```

With

```
alert(val1+val2);
```

Comment: its working thx you very much

Comment: solved thx you guys

Comment: You should tick my solution as the answer.

Comment: oh .. sorry i am new... i ticked it now

Answer (score 0):

alert("Answer = "+ansD.value);

Replace After  ansD.value = val1 + val2; line